# Excel Crashes setting worksheet visibility

Tags: excel, vba, crash

The following code consistently crashes Excel 2016 on my large workbook

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
    ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
Next ws
```

Stepping through the code, I find that it crashes after operating on a couple of dozen worksheets, but not on any specific worksheet. When it crashes, I need to kill Excel from the task manager, and it sometimes crashes Windows 10 itself to the BSOD. I suspect some kind of stack overflow problem. I've tried iterating through a list of worksheet names instead, with the same result. Any ideas?

Comment: try `ws.Visible = true` ?

Comment: *I suspect some kind of stack overflow problem* - and I expect some kind of [so] solution =)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try

```
newHour = Hour(Now()) 
newMinute = Minute(Now()) 
newSecond = Second(Now()) + x
waitTime = TimeSerial(newHour, newMinute, newSecond) 
Application.Wait (waitTime)
```

within your loop for some reasonable value of x (maybe 5). I suspect the compiler is "optimizing" and stacking a bunch of application requests, which is timing out the system.

PS I expect you know that ws should not be declared and that wb should be set to a workbook because those would cause issues.